# Troubles calculating $\mathrm{p.v.}\int_0^1\tan(\pi x)x\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

I want to evaluate the integral
$$\mathrm{p.v.}\int_0^1\tan(\pi x)x\,dx$$
with the Cauchy principal value $\mathrm{p.v}$. This integral converges, but just to be sure I also looked at the much simpler integral
$$\mathrm{p.v.}\int_0^1\tan(\pi x)x\,dx<\mathrm{p.v.}\int_0^1\frac{x}{\pi}\frac{2}{1-2x}=-\frac{1}{\pi},$$
this confirms the initial integral to be finite (in the Cauchy sense). To find the antiderivative I tried using Leibniz's formula on
$$\int\tan(ax)\,dx=-\frac{\ln\lvert\cos(ax)\rvert}{a}$$
to arrive at
$$\int\tan(\pi x)x\,dx=\frac{d}{da}\left.\int\tan(ax)\,dx\right|_{a=\pi}=\frac{\ln\lvert \cos(\pi x)\rvert}{\pi^2} + \frac{x \tan(\pi x))}{\pi}.$$
Using the definition of the Cauchy principal value, namely
\begin{align}
\mathrm{p.v.}\int_0^1\tan(\pi x)x\,dx &=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\left[\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon}\tan(\pi x)x\,dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon}^1\tan(\pi x)x\,dx\right]\\[5pt]
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\left[\frac{\ln\cos\left\lvert\pi (\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon)\right\rvert}{\pi^2} + \frac{(\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon) \tan\left(\pi (\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon)\right)}{\pi}\right.\\[5pt]
&\phantom{=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\left[\right.}\left.-\frac{\ln\cos\left\lvert\pi (\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon)\right\rvert}{\pi^2} - \frac{(\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon) \tan\left(\pi (\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon)\right)}{\pi}\right]
\end{align}
the limit diverges for $\varepsilon\to0^+$. I then also tried to manipulate the integral to become
$$\mathrm{p.v.}\int_0^1\tan(\pi x)x\,dx=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\tan(\pi x)(2x-1)\,dx\approx-0.22063560.$$
The value seems to be right, as I tried to evaluate the integral graphically, but I'd like to have the exact result. The other problem I encountered was that the antiderivative of the right integral also diverges for the upper limit:
$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\tan(\pi x)(2x-1)\,dx=\left[2\left(\frac{\ln\lvert \cos(\pi x)\rvert}{\pi^2} + \frac{x \tan(\pi x))}{\pi}\right)+\frac{\ln\lvert \cos(\pi x)\rvert}{\pi} \right]_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\to\infty.$$
I really don't understand where things went wrong and any help is highly appreciated.

**Edit:** I forgot to differentiate $\tan(a x)$ -.-, so the antiderivative isn't correct. Therefore my next question would be, if $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\tan(\pi x)(2x-1)\,dx$$ has a nice result.

**Edit2:** After consulting computer algebra systems I got a result for the integral:
$$\mathrm{p.v.}\int_0^1\tan(\pi x)x\,dx=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\tan(\pi x)(2x-1)\,dx=-\frac{\ln(2)}{\pi}.$$
I don't know how it did the evaluation, but it seems consistent with the numerics.

**Edit3:** Ok I got it. If we start from
$$\int_0^z\pi x\tan(\pi x)\,dx,$$
after recognizing that $\pi\tan(\pi x)=-\frac{d}{dx}\ln\cos(\pi x)$, we can do integration by parts to arrive at
$$-z\ln\cos(\pi z)+\int_0^z\ln\cos(\pi x)\,dx.$$
After some manipulations, we can recognize the Clausen function:
\begin{align}&-z\ln(2\cos(\pi z))+\int_0^z\ln(2\cos(\pi x))\,dx\\=&-z\ln(2\cos(\pi z))+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi z}\ln\left(2\cos\Big(\frac{x}{2}\Big)\right)\,dx\\=&-z\ln(2\cos(\pi z))+\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathrm{Cl}_2(\pi-2\pi z).\end{align}
Now going back to the original integral, we have
\begin{align}\int_0^{z}\tan(\pi x)(2x-1)\,dx&=2\int_0^{z}\tan(\pi x)x\,dx-\int_0^{z}\tan(\pi x)\,dx\\&=-\frac{2z}{\pi}\ln(2\cos(\pi z))+\frac{1}{\pi^2}\mathrm{Cl}_2(\pi-2\pi z)+\frac{\ln\cos(\pi z)}{\pi},\end{align}
which in the limit $z\to\frac{1}{2}$ gives $-\frac{\ln(2)}{\pi}$.

Comment: I don't agree with your $\int\tan(\pi x)x\,\mathrm{d}x$ equaling $\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int\tan(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x\right\vert_{a=\pi}$.  The latter being $\int\sec^2(ax) x\,\mathrm{d}x$ instead.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Uh... how did I forget to differentiate $\tan(ax)$. This is the kind of silliness I assumed would be the error.